# Can get an element inside an iFrame but .Click() does nothing

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe

I'm using Selenium from C# to try and periodically do a search on a website and pull in updated data. Unfortunately the website needs a login I can't make public so I can't actually give any kind of reproducible test case.

Using the Selenium IDE I've made a script that successfully logs in and pulls the data, so the task is possible. However when exporting that script to C#, there's a failure when trying to use an iframe that appears during the process.

By reading around I've discovered I need to add code to explicitly find and switch to the iframe, which I've done;

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("popup_iframe")));
```

Inside that frame is an area to the left with items to click. Each item when clicked changes the visible controls to the right. When I break at this point and click manually, everything works as expected. If I call the .Click on the IWebElement representing the object, nothing happens so the next step in the program fails because it gets another object, tries to click it and an exception's thrown because the object isn't visible.

I'm leaving 5s delays between operations in case delays are needed.

The code on the website in this area is;

```
<div id="ctl00_popup_workarea_left_container" class="popup-workarea-left-container" style="overflow: auto; height: 337px; display: block;">
 <a id="LBTN1" class="navbutton navbutton_Disabled_Selected">Basic Search</a>
 <a id="LBTN2" class="navbutton">Advanced Search</a>
 <a id="LBTN3" class="navbutton">Permit Holder Search</a>
 <a id="LBTN4" class="navbutton">Assessor Search</a>
</div>
```

The code I'm using to get and click the IWebElement is

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LBTN3")).Click();
```

I've also tried

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);          
act.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("LBTN3"))).Click().Perform();
```

Aside from the fact these don't throw exceptions, I've confirmed I'm getting an IWebElement interactively;

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LBTN3"))
{Element (id = f42435b5-139c-4334-be12-4a1f9f48221f)}
    Coordinates: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates}
    Displayed: true
    Enabled: true
    Id: "f42435b5-139c-4334-be12-4a1f9f48221f"
    Location: {X = 0 Y = 112}
    LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView: {X = 0 Y = 112}
    Selected: false
    Size: {Width = 200 Height = 29}
    TagName: "a"
    Text: "Permit Holder Search"
    WrappedDriver: {OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver}
```

So I'm getting the element. The HTML appears to show that it really is the element- I'm not accidentally using the ID of something containing it. The original script created in the Selenium IDE works fine- I just can't automate it so it kicks off unattended in the early hours. I know this is vague because I can't give people access to play to reproduce it, but does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Is the click working with Chrome?

Comment: Not sure what you mean- I'm working in Firefox since that seems to be preferred for Selenium/Webdriver. In Chrome it does work entirely manually, as it does in Firefox, and in Firefox if I breakpoint my code after it tries to click the button and I manually click the button before letting the code continue then the next steps execute correctly.

Comment: I meant is your C# code  working when executed with the Chrome  browser instead on the Firefox browser. If it works then it's a bug in the gecko driver. If not, then the reason is your code. But since you haven't posted a reproducible example, there's no way for us to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Have that issue currently with Chrome, didn't try with Firefox, but gonna try your script injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness I thought I'd better put an answer here.

I never identified *why* none of the attempts I made worked, but I discovered that injecting Javascript into the page to click the element I wanted to click did work. So assuming .FindElement() is able to get the element to click, the following snippet worked for me in a number of places where IWebElement.Click() proved uncooperative.

```
IWebElement ibtn3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LBTN3"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ibtn3);
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me in Chrome, I have tried all other combinations before that one worked, thanks for sharing